# export data in a rft datapool to excel in rft

Tags: rft

How to export data in RFT data pool to excel file ? I tried to directly open with excel but not able to view any content. Is there any other way?

Pls help.
Thanks in adv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export your datapool to a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file and then import it into Excel.

In RFT, go to File -> Export and select "Functional Test Datapool to CSV File", press Next, choose the datapool you want and the appropriate separator character, usually the comma `,` but you can choose another if your data contains such character. [image: Exporting as CSV file]

Answer (score 0):

In RFT, go to File -> Export and select "Functional Test Datapool to CSV File", press Next, choose the datapool file select the existing file or Enter new file name, Click on finish button. The file will saved in .csv format. And on opening using excel should open the file in excel.